# Layout Fidelity warning

Tags: android, layout

I am on day one here, sorry for any stupid questions...

I am using android studio 2.3.1 
I made an new blank app and placed a few buttons and some text.

When I run the phone emulator it crams everything from my design page into the top left and I get a render error saying !layout fidelity warning (the graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate)

I followed the youtube video I was watching step by step and theirs seemed to run fine, any idea what I have to do to fix this ?

Comment: Can you share your layout?

Comment: Nevermind, I was not in RelativeLayout in the Text, ty though : )

Comment: I was in constrained somehow... anyway if you have the same probelm just change it from constrained to this on line 2          <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: Layout Fidelity Warning is exactly what it say. Its a **warning**! Won't affect your app. Just ignore it.